# Почему перекидывает сразу в локалхост?

Tags: php, mysql

Формируется меню в файду menu.php

```
<?php
function menu($id) {
$zapros=mysql_query("select * from menu_admin where id_id={$id}") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($zapros)){
echo "<li><a href='/index.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a><ul>";
menu ($row['id']);
echo "</ul></li>";
}
}
menu (0);
?>
```

В файле index.php пытаемся связать это меню с продолжением

```
require_once "menu.php";
$id=0;
if ($_GET['id']) $id=$_GET['id'];
if ($id===5){
echo("OK");
}
```

Но там, где должно было показаться ОК, меня перекидывает сразу на локалхост в корневой раздел, а не вовсе на ОК. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: После нажатия на ссылку в адресной строке браузера что написано?

Answer (score 1):

у Вас путь от корня сайта

```
echo "<li><a href='/index.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a><ul>";
```

он точно верен? Думаю, стоит убрать слеш перед index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в том, что вы используете сравнение "Идентично" - "`===`". Почитайте мануал. Данные из $_GET у Вас всегда строка, пока вы ее не преобразуете. Вот программа и пытается сравнить не только значения но и типы. В данном случае значения равны, а типы нет - `str<>int`.

Решение - использовать просто сравнение "`==`". Либо добавить приведение типов (int).

```
require_once "menu.php"; 
$id=0; 
if ($_GET['id']) 
$id=$_GET['id']; 
if ((int)$id===5) //или if ($id==5)
{ 
  echo("OK"); 
}
```

Comment: Пробовал и == результат один

Comment: Как вы обращаетесь к скрипту? index.php?id=5

Comment: Исправил промежуточную ошибку. Теперь пишет, ваша ссылка не найдена на сервере

>Object not found!

>The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

>If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: попробуйте так:
href='".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/index.php?id={$row['id']}'

Вообще если в адресную строку ввести http://site.name/index.php?id=5 - срабатывает?

Comment: срабатывает и что?

Comment: если срабатывает - значит ищите проблему в href ваших ссылок в меню. Должен быть правильный путь. Ошибка именно там